# Discretization of Newton's Equation with velocity perpendicular to gradient

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, computational-physics, discrete

Suppose I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)=\nabla_xf(x)$ and $H(x) = \nabla^2 f(x)$ are its gradient and Hessian matrix. I have the following ODE system
$$
\begin{align}
\dot x(t) &= v(t) \\
\dot v(t) &= - \frac{v(t)^\top H(x_t) v(t)}{||g(x(t))||^2} g(x(t))
\end{align}
$$
with initial condition $(x_0, v_0)$ with $v_0\perp g(x_0)$. Clearly $\frac{d}{dt} v(t)^\top g(x(t)) = 0$ so that the velocity stays perpendicular to the gradient $v_t\perp g(x(t))$. I would like to discretize this ODE. I have read about Euler, Verlet and Leapfrog methods. Usually, when you have the system
$$
\dot x(t) = v(t) \\
\dot v(t) = a(t)
$$
the Leapfrog method workds well. However everyone seems to say this is not a good method to use when the force/acceleration depends on the velocity, as in this case. The lecture notes say that this system of equations  could be discretized as
$$
\begin{align}
x_{t + \delta/2} &= x_t + \frac{\delta}{2}v_t \\
v_{t+\delta} &=v_t - \delta \frac{v(t)^\top H(x_{t + \delta/2}) v(t)}{||g(x_{t + \delta/2})||^2} g(x_{t + \delta/2}) \\
x_{t+\delta} &= x_{t + \delta/2} + \frac{\delta}{2} v_{t + \delta}
\end{align}
$$
but doesn't explain why this is the correct scheme and what scheme this even is. To me it looks like a wrong Leapfrog method where they are doing things in reverse: doing half a position step, a full velocity step and half a position step. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: The method you have included and you are asking about doesn't seem to keep the discrete trajectory on the same potential surface. But maybe I am missing something? It emulates Leapfrog, but you are right maybe not quite Leapfrog. Also, from what I understand, you want the point to move on a the (hyper-)surface by the potential of fixed value $f(x) = f(x_0)$. Is that correct? I wrote a post on Leapfrog once, if you want, take a look: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36394/time-reversibility-of-velocity-verlet-algorithm/36543#36543

Comment: @Futurologist Thank you for the blog post, will definitely have a look now! Exactly, unfortunately, there is no explanation. Perhaps there is a typo?

Comment: Just to warn you, the post I recommended is not a comprehensive discussion. I cannot claim I am an expert in the field of leapfrog/Verlet integration. I am just a user who tried to understand its structure from a geometric point of view. Your case is actually an ambient representation of the geodesic flow on an equipotential surface of the potential $f(x)$. Do you want me to try to cook up a method and suggest it to you?

Comment: @Futurologist The sentence "geodesic flow on an equipotential surface of the potential $f(x)$" is so helpful. Not knowing this area of maths, I feel so lost in googling terms and concepts. How did you find out that it's a geodesic on an equipotetial surface? And if you could do it or even just point me in the right direction, that would be amazing.

Comment: @Futurologist I can also show you what I have tried. BTW Are these kinds of ODEs well studied?

Comment: I do not know about the literature and whether these equations have been studied. Possibly the have been in one form or another. I am more of a do it yourself. The fact that what you showed in your question is the geodesic flow on the equipotential hyper-surface occurred to me while I looked at the equations and interpreted them geometrically. And I noticed. Feel free to share what you have attempted. I posted an answer with a scheme, based on geometric approach, rather than direct numerics. I am a bit busy these days and I answered hastily, but I hope you can get what you can from my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned, your system is the system of differential equations, written in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^m$, of the geodesics on the equipotential surface $f(x) = c$.

So let us have a smooth function $$f \, : \, \mathbb{R}^m \, \longrightarrow \, \mathbb{R}$$ which we call 'the potential', and let us fix a real number (a value) $c \,\in \, \mathbb{R}$ which gives us the smooth level hyper-surface
$$M_c \, = \, \{ \, x \, \in \, \mathbb{R}^m \,\, | \,\,\, f(x) = c\,\,\}$$
If you restrict the standard flat Euclidean metric on $M_c$ you get a Riemannian metric on $M_c$. Now, the geodesics of $M_c$ are not geodesics of $\mathbb{R}^m$, the latter are just straight lines, but the geodesics of $M_c$ try to follow the curved surface of $M_c$ with as little deviation from the ambient geodesics as possible. Which means that their acceleration, that causes them to curve and follow the surface instead of staying straight, when orthogonally projected onto the tangent space of $M_c$ at each point on the geodesic, should be zero (so no acceleration should be visible for creatures on the surface, that do not look into the ambient space). What is that mean. Let $x = x(t)$ be a geodesic on $M_c$. Then the acceleration should be its second derivative, i.e.
$$\text{acceleration} \, = \,  \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$
Furthermore, since the orthogonal projection of $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ onto the tangent space of $M_c$ at the point $x$ should be zero, that means that
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} \,\,\text{ should be aligned with the normal vector to $M_c$ at $x$ }$$
But a normal vector to $M_c$ at $x$ is the gradient $g(x) \, = \, \nabla f(x)$ so
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} \,\,\text{ should be aligned with the normal vector $\nabla f(x)$ }$$
And there you have the first hint, that the equations of the geodesic should look like
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} \, = \, \lambda \, \nabla f(x)$$ where you can expect
$$\lambda \, = \, \lambda\Big(x, \, \frac{dx}{dt}\Big)$$
Combine the latter system of equation with the restriction $$f(x) \, = \, c$$
When you differentiate the latter restriction with respect to $t$, you get the first new restriction
$$\nabla f(x)^T \, \frac{dx}{dt} \, = \, 0$$
i.e. the velocity $\frac{dx}{dt}(t)$ of $x(t)$ is always perpendicular to $\nabla f(x)$, which means the velocity is tangent to the hyper-surface $M_c$ (which is not surprising, it is expected and required). Now, we go even further and differentiate the latter dot product identity once more with respect to $t$ and get
$$\nabla f(x)^T \, \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} \, + \, \frac{dx}{dt}^T H_f(x) \, \frac{dx}{dt} \, = \, 0$$
Plug $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} \, = \, \lambda \, \nabla f(x)$ into the latter identity and you get

$$\nabla f(x)^T \, \big(\lambda \, \nabla f(x)\,\big) \, + \, \frac{dx}{dt}^T H_f(x) \, \frac{dx}{dt} \, = \, 0$$

$$\lambda \, \nabla f(x)^T \,  \, \nabla f(x) \, + \, \frac{dx}{dt}^T H_f(x) \, \frac{dx}{dt} \, = \, 0$$

$$\lambda \, \big| \nabla f(x) \big|^2  \, + \, \frac{dx}{dt}^T H_f(x) \, \frac{dx}{dt} \, = \, 0$$ so when you solve for $\lambda$ you get

$$\lambda \, = \, - \, \frac{\, \frac{dx}{dt}^T H_f(x) \, \frac{dx}{dt} \,}{\big| \nabla f(x) \big|^2}$$

And now you see that the system of differential equations for the geodesics on $M_c$, written with variables from the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^m$, is

\begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{dt} \, = \, v\\
&\frac{dv}{dt} \, = \, -\, \frac{\, v^T H_f(x) \, v \,}{\big| \nabla f(x) \big|^2}\,\,\nabla f(x)
\end{align}
with initial conditions and restrictions
\begin{align}
&x(0) \, = \, x_0\\
&v(0) \, = \, v_0\\
&f(x_0) \, = \, c\\
&\nabla f(x_0)^T\,v_0 \, = \, 0
\end{align}
Then, any solution to the system of equations that satisfies the initial restrictions will keep satisfying them for all times $t$, i.e. for all $t$

\begin{align}
&f\big(x(t)\big) \, = \, c\\
&\nabla f\big(\,x(t)\,\big)^T\,v(t) \, = \, 0
\end{align}

That's because the equations have been constructed to satisfy these conditions in the first place. By differentiating these identities once and twice and combine with the initial restrictions, you can verify the identities for all $t$, which we actually already did in order to determine the exact formula for $\lambda$.

One more observation. The magnitude of the velocity $v(t)$ is constant for all $t$. Indeed

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\,
\big(\,\, |v|^2 \,\big) \, =& \, 2 \, v^T \, \frac{dv}{dt} \, = \, 2\, v^T \left( \,  -\, \frac{\, v^T H_f(x) \, v \,}{\big| \nabla f(x) \big|^2}\,\,\nabla f(x) \, \right)\\
=& \, 2\, \left( \,  -\, \frac{\, v^T H_f(x) \, v \,}{\big| \nabla f(x) \big|^2}  \right) \Big(\, v^T\, \nabla f(x) \, \Big)\\
=& \, 2\, \left( \,  -\, \frac{\, v^T H_f(x) \, v \,}{\big| \nabla f(x) \big|^2}  \right) \Big(\, \nabla f(x)^T v \, \Big)\\
=& \, 2\, \left( \,  -\, \frac{\, v^T H_f(x) \, v \,}{\big| \nabla f(x) \big|^2}  \right)\cdot 0\\
=& \, 0
\end{align}

so $|v(t)| = |v_0| = v_0$ is constant for all $t$ (another feature of the geodesic flow).

In the light of this analysis, I would try to develop and implement a time-discrete version of the geodesic flow on $M_c$, replicating as many of the properties above as possible, instead of trying direct blind numerics for the differential equations.

Here is my suggestion:

**A discrete geodesic flow on the hyper-equipotential surface $M_c$ of the function $f(x)$ with fixed small step $h$.**

Assume you have generated the following pair of position and velocity
$$\big(\,x_n,\, v_n\,\big)$$
satisfying the restrictions

\begin{align}
&f(x_n) \, = \, c\\
&\nabla f(x_n)^T\,v_n  =\, 0\\
&|v_n| \, = \, v_0
\end{align}

**Step 1.** Generate the new intermediate position $$\tilde{x}_n \, = \, x_n \, + \, h\,v_n$$

**Step 2.** Solve the non-linear system of $n+1$ equations for the unknown $n+1$ variables
$\big(\,x_{n+1}, \,\, \lambda_{n+1}\,\big)$

\begin{align}
&\lambda_{n+1}\nabla f(x_{n+1}) \, + \, x_{n+1} \, = \, \tilde{x}_n\\
&f(x_{n+1}) \, = \, c
\end{align}

Geometrically, this system tells you that $x_{n+1}$ is the orthogonal projection of $\tilde{x}_{n}$ onto the hyper-surface $M_c$ along the normal vector $\nabla f(x_{n+1})$ of $M_c$, calculated at the projected point $x_{n+1}$. In other words, $x_{n+1}$ is chosen on the hyper-surface $M_c$ so that the $\lambda-$parametrized line $$x_{n+1} \, + \, \lambda \nabla f(x_{n+1})\, , $$ which is orthogonal to $M_c$, passes through the point $\tilde{x}_n$. As you can see, here we have $\lambda_{n+1}\nabla f(x_{n+1}) $ which is the discrete analogue of the orthogonal force that keeps the geodesic on the hyper-surface $M_c$ preventing it from escaping into the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^m$.

You can try to solve this system of non-linear equation by say Newton's method, for which you will need the hessian $H_f(x)$ and that's where the hessian appears in this discrete scheme. So, start with initial conditions $x^0_{n+1} \, = \,\tilde{x}_n,\,\, \lambda^0_{n+1} = 0$. Then keep iterating over $k$, with $n$ fixed, and keep solving the linear system for the new variables $\big(\,x_{n+1}^{k+1}, \,\, v_{n+1}^{k+1}\, \big)$ form the previous already known variables $\big(\,x_{n+1}^{k}, \,\, v_{n+1}^{k}\, \big)$ calculate the Jacobian

$$
\Big[\,J_{n+1}^k\,\Big] \, = 
\,\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{n+1}^k H_f({x}_{n+1}^k) + I_{m\times m} & \nabla f({x}_{n+1}^k)\\
\nabla f({x}_{n+1}^k)^T & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

and then use it as the matrix for the system of linear equations for the unknown variables $\big(\,x_{n+1}^{k+1}, \,\, v_{n+1}^{k+1}\, \big)$

$$
\Big[\,J_{n+1}^k\,\Big]  \begin{bmatrix} x_{n+1}^{k+1}\\ \lambda_{n+1}^{k+1}\end{bmatrix} \, = \, \Big[\,J_{n+1}^k\,\Big]  \begin{bmatrix} x_{n+1}^{k}\\ \lambda_{n+1}^{k}\end{bmatrix} \, - \, \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{n+1}\nabla f(x_{n+1}^{k}) \, + \, x_{n+1}^{k} \, - \, \tilde{x}_n\\  f(x_{n+1}^k) \, - \, c\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$k =  k + 1$$

until $$|f(x_{n+1}^{k}) \, - \, c|^2 \,<\, \varepsilon$$ for some fixed $\varepsilon$ threshold error.

In attempt to save computational time and memory (hopefully it works), maybe you can try to cheat a bit and calculate the Jacobian for Newton's method only at the initial conditions $x^0_{n+1} \, = \,\tilde{x}_n,\,\, \lambda^0_{n+1} = \lambda_{n}$ (or $\lambda_{n+1}^0 = 0$ which allows you to skip the hessian altogether, but I do not know if it works) and keep reusing it. Here $\lambda_n$ is the result from the calculation from the previous point $x_n$.

So first, calculate and invert the following Jacobian at $\tilde{x}_n$

$$
\Big[\,\text{J inv} \, \Big] \, = 
\,\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{n+1}^0 H_f(\tilde{x}_n) + I_{m \times m} & \nabla f(\tilde{x}_{n})\\
\nabla f(\tilde{x}_{n})^T & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
$$

Second, again starting from initial conditions $x^0_{n+1} \, = \,\tilde{x}_n,\,\, \lambda^0_{n+1} = 0$ (or $\lambda^0_{n+1} = \lambda_n$ from the preceding calculation for $x_n$), and while $$|f(x_{n+1}^{k}) \, - \, c|^2 \,\geq \, \varepsilon$$ keep iterating over $k$ the discrete dynamical system
$$\begin{bmatrix} x_{n+1}^{k+1}\\ \lambda_{n+1}^{k+1}\end{bmatrix} \, = \, \begin{bmatrix} x_{n+1}^{k}\\ \lambda_{n+1}^{k}\end{bmatrix} \, - \, \Big[\,\text{J inv} \, \Big] \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{n+1}\nabla f(x_{n+1}^{k}) \, + \, x_{n+1}^{k} \, - \, \tilde{x}_n\\  f(x_{n+1}^k) \, - \, c\end{bmatrix}$$
$$k =  k + 1$$
The result is the new position $x_{n+1}$, which is on the surface $M_c$ (numerically :) )

**Step 3.** Finally, we calculate the new velocity $v_{n+1}$. We project orthogonally the old velocity $v_n$ onto the tangent hyper-plane of $M_c$ at the new position $x_{n+1}$ and then we rescale it to have magnitude $v_0$

\begin{align}
&\tilde{v}_n \, = \, v_n \, - \, \left(\,\frac{\,\nabla f(x_{n+1})^T \, v_n\,}{|\nabla f(x_{n+1})|^2}\,\right)\, \nabla f(x_{n+1})\\
&v_{n+1} \, = \, v_0 \, \frac{\tilde{v}_n}{|\tilde{v}_n|}
\end{align}

As you can see here, just like in the smooth case, the velocities $v_{n+1}$ and $v_n$ are coplanar with the normal gradient vector $\nabla f(x_{n+1})$. And again, you can see that the velocity evolves only along the normal gradient vector $\nabla f(x_{n+1})$, which is the discrete analogue of the normal force redirecting the velocity in the smooth case.

By executing steps 1, 2 and 3 we obtain the new position and velocity of the geodesic flow

$$\big(\,x_{n+1},\, v_{n+1}\,\big)$$

By construction, the new pair also satisfies the geodesic restrictions

\begin{align}
&f(x_{n+1}) \, = \, c\\
&\nabla f(x_{n+1})^T\,v_{n+1}  =\, 0\\
&|v_{n+1}| \, = \, v_0
\end{align}

By iterating steps 1, 2, 3 you get a discrete analogue of the geodesic flow on $M_c$. And I think the result will have a fairly good behaviour and will emulate many of the properties of the smooth geodesic flow.

**Edit.** As a test, I implemented this method for the case of the geodesic flow on a 3D ellipsoid. I chose an ellipsoid whose axes are aligned with the coordinate axes. I implemented the method using a fixed Jacobian for Newton's method, when generating the orthogonal projection of the intermediate point onto the surface of the ellipsoid. It works quite well, so for nice surfaces probably there is no need to calculate a hessian, which is good news.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Jacobian_inv(z_, A):
    grad = A.dot(z_[0:3])
    J = np.empty((4,4), dtype=float)
    J[0:3,0:3] = np.diag([1,1,1])
    J[0:3, 3] = grad 
    J[3, 0:3] = 2*grad
    J[3,3] = 0.
    return np.linalg.inv(J)

def project_position(z_med, A, accuracy):
    z = z_med
    J_1 = Jacobian_inv(z, A)
    while True:
        Ax = A.dot(z[0:3])
        xAx_1 = z[0:3].dot(Ax) - 1.
        if abs(xAx_1) < accuracy:
            return z
        F = np.concatenate(  ( z[3]*Ax + z[0:3] - z_med[0:3],  np.array([xAx_1]) )  )
        z = z - J_1.dot(F)

def project_velocity(x_, v_, norm_v, A):
    Ax = A.dot(x_)
    v = v_ - (Ax.dot(v_))*Ax / Ax.dot(Ax)
    return norm_v * v / np.sqrt(v.dot(v))

def geod_flow_step(z_, v_, norm_v, A, accuracy, step):
    z = np.concatenate(  ( z_[0:3] + step * v_,   np.array([0.]) )  )
    z = project_position(z, A, accuracy)
    v = project_velocity(z[0:3], v_, norm_v, A)
    return z, v

def geod_flow(x_in, v_in, A, norm_v, accuracy, step, n_steps):
    n = n_steps #int(arc_length / step)
    x = np.empty((n, 3), dtype=float)
    v = np.empty((n, 3), dtype=float)
    x[0,:] = x_in
    v[0,:] = v_in
    z = np.array([x_in[0], x_in[1], x_in[2], 0.0])
    for m in range(n-1):
        z, v[m+1,:] = geod_flow_step(z, v[m,:], norm_v, A, accuracy, step)
        x[m+1,:] = z[0:3]
    return x, v
    

x0 = np.array([3., 0., 0.])
v0 = np.array([0., 1., 2.])
semi_axes = np.array([3.*3., 2.*2, 1.*1.])
D = np.diag(1. / semi_axes)
norm_v0 = 1.
accuracy = 1e-7
step = 0.05

v0 = v0 / np.linalg.norm(v0)
v0 = norm_v0 * v0 
 

x, v = geod_flow(x0, v0, D, norm_v0, accuracy, step, 1500)

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim((-4, 4))
ax.set_ylim((-4, 4))
ax.set_zlim((-4, 4))

ax.plot(x[:,0], x[:,1], x[:,2], 'r-')
ax.plot(x[0,0], x[0,1], x[0,2], 'bo')
ax.plot(x[-1,0], x[-1,1], x[-1,2], 'go')
plt.show()
```

Starting point $[3, 0, 0]$ and direction vector $[0, 1, 1]$

[image]

Starting point $[3, 0, 0]$ and direction vector $[0, 1, 2]$
[image]

Starting point $[3, 0, 0]$ and direction vector $[0, 1, 3]$
[image]

The blue point is the starting point, the green one is the endpoint.

**Geodesic on a submanifold of a Euclidean space.** A geodesic on a manifold is a curve whose covariant derivative (i.e. derivative within the framework of the manifold's geometry) is zero. This means that there is no acceleration on the manifold that makes the geodesic turn, so the geodesic is straight within the manifold's geometry. However, in our case, the manifold is a hyper-surface in some Euclidean space. So the geometry of this hyper-surface is inherited from the ambient Euclidean geometry. A geodesic on the hyper-surface doesn't curve as seen from the hyper-surface, but it definitely curves in the ambient Euclidean space, because the hyper-surface itself is not straight (unless it is hyper-plane) and the geodesic itself is not a straight line. So, the geodesic should curve in the ambient space but should not curve from the point of view of the hyper-surface. That means that the acceleration vector of the geodesic, which exists in the Euclidean space, should not be visible on the hyper-surface. This last statement simply means that the orthogonal projection of this acceleration on the tangent hyper-plane of the hyper-surface at each point on the geodesic should not exist, i.e. it should be zero. This is true exactly when the acceleration vector at each point of the geodesic in the Euclidean space is perpendicular to the tangent plane at that point. The gradient of the hype-surface is also perpendicular to the tangent hyper-plane at each point from the hyper-surface. Hence, the acceleration vector and the gradient must be colinear, i.e. aligned.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Will take me a while to go through it!

Comment: @Euler_Salter I had to make some corrections in the calculations for the Jacobian, so make sure to read that section again. I also added some comments here and there, but not super important.

Comment: Hey @Futurologist, thank you again! I read a few times and that's so helpful. In the first section I understand that $f(x)=c$ gives rise to $\nabla f(x)^\top \dot x = 0$ as well as the equation obtained by differentiating it again wrt time. However, I am still a bit puzzled by the very initial explanation where you say that the acceleration is parallel to the gradient. Do you mind explaning it again?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I added some test implementation of the method in python for the case of the geodesics on an ellipsoid in 3D space. I also added some heuristic explanation of the acceleration of a geodesic being always perpendicular to the hyper-surface.